# word Isn't equal to wordlist.readline() even though it is

Tags: python, loops, readline

Here's my code:

```
wordlist = open('words.txt')

word = input()
i = 0

def loop():
    for i in range(466549):
        if wordlist.readline().strip() == word:
            print(f'found in {i}')
            return
        else:
            print(f"not {wordlist.readline()}")
            i = i + 1
            
loop()
```

Not only does it not return the first value of the list, but it also doesn't say that it found my word when it did. I got my words.txt file from GitHub, and the second word is "1080". But when I put that in, it prints 'not 1080' even though it clearly is.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: `"1080."` and `"1080"` are not the same thing.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy My bad, I meant to put the period after the quotes.

Comment: dude you are using the same variable `i` for 2 different tasks. change one of them to another letter.

Comment: The code has a lot of issues with file reading, maybe you can consult a tutorial? You haven't closed the file, and each `readline` call consumes 1 line, so you are effectively skipping every alternate line. When it prints "not 1080", that is actually the error for the line before 1080

Comment: @AV_69 im using it for the same thing, the `i` in `print(f'found in {1}')` to display the line

Comment: please assign a different variable name for (I) in the else statement.                             `i = i + 1`  ie `a=i+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
word = input("enter word: ").strip()

def loop():
    with open("words.txt") as f:
        wordList = f.readlines()
        for i,line in enumerate(wordList):
            line = line.strip()
            if line == word:
                print(f"found in line {i}")
                return
            else:
                print(f"did not find in {line}")


loop()
```

or if you want to stick to using just `readline`:

```
word = input("enter word: ").strip()
wordList = open("words.txt")

def loop():
   for i in range(466549):
       line = wordList.readline().strip()
       if line == word:
          print(f"found in line {i}")
          return
       else:
          print(f"did not find in {line}")


loop()
wordList.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna find if specific word in text file.

First, `wordlist.readline()` actually reads a line from file which means it is not **reproducible**. so, `print(f"not {wordlist.readline()}")` doesn't work as you expected.

For example, let's say `words.txt` looks like below.

```
hello
1080
world
```

When you read first line with `if wordlist.readline() ...`  inside loop, that value is "hello", and this is not `1080`, so `else` statement runs. At here, you reads a line with `print(f"not {wordlist.readline()}")` as second which is `1080`, thus `not 1080` gonna be printed.

And finally, `if wordlist.readline() ...`  will read `world` from file, this is also not `1080`, and next `readline()` will be None.

Secondary problem is that variable `i` is not utilized properly. `i` is incremented automatically thanks to `range` and `for` keyword (Strictly, it just next value from iterable object, not increment), so you don't need like `i = 0` or `i = i + 1`

Third thing is derived from the problem pointed in first one, which is `None.strip()` is impossible so it will raise an exception.

There are more things to say, but I'll just show you my example so you can compare it with yours

```py
input_wordlist = open('words.txt')
input_word = input()

def loop(word, wordlist):
    for index, line in enumerate(wordlist.readlines()):
        if line.strip() == word:
        # or if you wanna know whether word is in line
        # if word in line:
            print(f"found in {index}")
            return
        else:
            print(f"not in {line}")

loop(input_word, input_wordlist)
input_wordlist.close()
```